# React HOC function does not spread props into html element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I got simple sample. I want to pass any component to a function and get it with set background.
Works OK with `React.createElement` components, but does not work for html components.

```js
const Title = ({ children }) => {
    return (<h1 data-this-works="test">{children}</h1>)
}

const Box = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
    return React.createElement('span', rest, children)
}

const styleComponent = BaseComponent => ({children, ...props}) => {
 const style = {backgroundColor: 'green'}

  return (
    <BaseComponent style={style} {...props} >
      {children}
    </BaseComponent>
  );
}

const StyledTitle = styleComponent(Title)
const StyledBox = styleComponent(Box)


class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
    <div>
      <StyledTitle>Title</StyledTitle>
      <StyledBox>Box</StyledBox>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Constantinff/g357tfv9/8/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Title` doesn't spread any props to the `h1`. `Box` works because you're passing `rest` as the props in `React.createElement` - you need to do the same for the `h1`.

```js
const Title = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
    return (<h1 data-this-works="test" {...rest}>{children}</h1>)
}

const Box = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
    return React.createElement('span', rest, children)
}

const styleComponent = BaseComponent => ({children, ...props}) => {
 const style = {backgroundColor: 'green'}

  return (
    <BaseComponent style={style} {...props} >
      {children}
    </BaseComponent>
  );
}

const StyledTitle = styleComponent(Title)
const StyledBox = styleComponent(Box)


class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
    <div>
      <StyledTitle>Title</StyledTitle>
      <StyledBox>Box</StyledBox>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```